# Picture not showing on my loading screen in QLabel

Tags: python, pyqt, qt-designer

I'm currently using QT designer to show a picture on my loading screen.

It should look like this:
[image]

However, it looks like this:
[image]

This is because for some reason its not showing my picture, when it registers in my IDE that the filepath is correct as seen here: [image]

The only time the picture actually shows in my loading GUI is when I use the FULL file path which is: `C:\Users\myalt\OneDrive\Desktop\GUINEW\assets\PostmonkeyLogo.png`

But of course, this is not viable when this software will be used on many different computer with different file paths.

```
self.label.setPixmap(QPixmap(u"assets/PostmonkeyLogo.png")) ## image file path to show
```

Comment: try using fullpath, please provide a [MRE]

Comment: I said at the end of my post that it works when using full filepaths, but this is not a viable option. 

https://pastebin.com/28jbTH7e

Comment: So if partial path doesn't work but full path does, then your starting path/working directory must not be what you think it is. You should determine what your working directory is so that you can place the files to be able to work with relative paths correctly.

Comment: After testing this it comes up with: C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2020.2\jbr\bin

This could be because of my VE in my pycharm IDE?

print(os.getcwd())

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the file path is relative to where the console was opened and the python.exe command is executed. It is better to build the full path using the information as the path of the .py:

```py
import os.path

# ...

CURRENT_DIRECTORY = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
filename = os.path.join(CURRENT_DIRECTORY, "assets/PostmonkeyLogo.png")
self.label.setPixmap(QPixmap(filename))
```